# Most efficient way to filter when some conditions must be linked?

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have this task where I want to show certain content to people based on optional questions they can answer. Here's a similar, simplified example:

People can choose out of three categories: mood, height, color. They have a limited number of options for each. You can only be one mood and height, but you can be multiple colors. So, person A might choose happy, tall, blue. Person B could be sad, short, green, yellow, and purple. Person C could be frustrated and orange.

Based on what they choose, some image will be shown to them. But some of the images are dependent on only certain combinations. For instance, one image is shown to all people who are tall. Another is for those who are happy or sad *and* blue. Yet another image is only shown to people who are either sad and green (only) *or* happy and purple (only).

I am doing this with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript/jQuery. I've been thinking about using a different data type for each category. Then I was thinking I should have a different data type for mood, height, and each different color (which would be filled with a yes or no). Then, looking at some filtering plugins online, I thought maybe I would just do it with classes. But these would all pose a problem for when certain classes had to be linked.

The image is just an example; in reality there is quite a bit of content that will need to be displayed so I'm trying to find the lightest solution.

I know I can probably write some nested loops to accomplish this. I have also been considering connecting certain classes with a hyphen after they are entered and filtering for that. (eg., from above: if someone answers they are sad and green, connect those after they enter it as sad-green and then have the specific content tagged with sad-green). That way, I could have a limited number of classes (which could be combined) without having to make crazy amounts of different classes.

I'm not sure which would be best, or if I'm (probably) missing some obvious, elegant way to accomplish this. Any suggestions would be appreciated; thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the top, this sounds like a [chain of responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design, with regards to letting the case you have go through each rule until it is caught by the first one that applies. Of course, in your case it sounds more like a [tree of responsibility](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20108/Extending-Chain-of-Responsibility-Design-Pattern), but in it could be done using switch-cases, or something similar. Taking on your example, using `c#` syntax:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Height;
    public string Mood;
    public List<string> Colour;
}

public void Decide(Person someone)
{
    switch (someone.Height)
    {
        case "tall":
            DecideOnColour(someone);
            break;

        case "short":
            DecideOnMood(someone);
            break;
    }
}

public void DecideOnColour(Person someone)
{
    foreach (string colour in someone.Colour)
    {
        switch (someone.Colour)
        {
            //Do something...
        }
    }

    if (someone.Colour.Contains("Green"))
        // Do something else...
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I am self-taught at programming so the links you gave are super helpful as well. It's hard to use Google to learn when I don't know the appropriate terminology. I'm off to read about those things. The use of switch had entered my mind, but I hadn't thought it through yet. Thanks again!